# Storing metadata about a row with a database row?

Tags: sql, sql-server, schema, auditing

What are the best practices regarding storing metadata *about* a row *with* a row?

Take the example of a inter-bank financial transfer. The `Transfer` might look like:

```
CREATE TABLE Transfers (
   TransferID int,
   FromTransit varchar(10),
   FromBranch varchar(10),
   FromAccount varchar(50),
   ToTransit varchar(10),
   ToBranch varchar(10),
   ToAccount varchar(50),
   Amount money,
   Status varchar(50));
```

But now, of course, people will want to see meta-data:

```
ALTER TABLE Transfers 
ADD
    CreatedDate datetime,
    LastModifiedDate datetime,
    CreatedByUsername varchar(50),
    CreatedByFullname varchar(200),
    CreatedByWorkstation varchar(50),

    VoidedDate datetime NULL,
    VoidedByUsername datetime NULL,
    VoidedByFullname datetime NULL,
    VoidApprovedBySupervisorUsername varchar(50) NULL,
    VoidApprovedBySupervisorFullname varchar(200) NULL,
    VoidApprovedBySupervisorWorkstation varchar(50) NULL,

    SentDate datetime NULL, 
    SentByUsername varchar(50) NULL,
    SentByFullname varchar(50) NULL,
    SentByWorkstation varchar(50) NULL,
    SendApprovedBySupervisorUsername varchar(50) NULL,
    SendApprovedBySupervisorFullname varchar(50) NULL,
    SendApprovedBySupervisorWorkstation varchar(50) NULL,
    SendConfirmationNumber varchar(50) NULL,
    SentToRemoteMachineName varchar(50) NULL,

    ReceivedDate datetime NULL, 
    ReceivedConfirmationNumber varchar(50) NULL,
    ReceivedToRemoteMachineName varchar(50) NULL,
    ReceivedByUsername varchar(50) NULL,
    ReceivedByFullname varchar(50) NULL,
    ReceivedByWorkstation varchar(50) NULL,
    ReceiveApprovedBySupervisorUsername varchar(50) NULL,
    ReceiveApprovedBySupervisorFullname varchar(50) NULL,
    ReceivedApprovedBySupervisorWorkstation varchar(50) NULL,

    ReceivedCheckedBySupervisorUsername varchar(50) NULL,
    ReceivedCheckedBySupervisorFullname varchar(50) NULL,
    ReceivedCheckedBySupervisorWorkstation varchar(50) NULL
)
```

These are all well-defined values, that will all appear on the hard-copy related to a transfer.

We already have audit logging of changes in tables, but that wouldn't catch something like:

```
UPDATE Transfers SET Status = 'TransferStatus_Received'
WHERE TransferID = 6744891
```

It would catch the *username*, *fullname*, and *machine name* of the person who made the change; but it can't know the name of the supervisor who was over the person's shoulder to enter their credentials to "authorize" the transfer to be received.

My aggravation comes when they ask for *another* piece of information to be tracked, and I have to add more **metadata** columns to my **data** table.

Is this best practice?

Comment: I don't see how this is a security related question.

Comment: @Rook Some customers have governments breathing down their neck, that demand we log all kinds of things; in case someone tries to steal a few million dollars. i personally don't care if government employee steals my tax money, but some members of the public get grumpy over that sort of thing. Those members of the public don't keep their displeasure to themselves, but call their congressmen, who then demand tighter security. Including the ability to log and audit everything.

Answer (score 2):

This is not good practice for financial databases because you allow updates. If you allow updates it does not matter what logging, auditing, crypto keys or whatever you add since a hostile party could just update them.

Instead you must forbid updates; all changes must be inserts. All tables should have an indexed sequential FK column and all joins are on `Max(seq)`. This means you perform all transactions on the latest data but have a permanent record of every transaction on these tables.

Edit: If what you're asking is whether you should add the audit columns to the original table, that depends if the audit columns are sparse or nullable. From your comments, it seems they are.

In that case, you should create separate tables for each nullable group of audit attributes and perform an outer join on those tables, joining with the sequential column of the original database. This means you can add or drop audit tables at will without affecting your data table. Something like:

```
SELECT t.transferID, t.money, u.Date, u.workstation, s.name, ...
FROM Transfers t
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Users u ON u.seq = t.seq
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Supervisors s ON s.seq = t.seq
WHERE t.seq = (SELECT Max(seq) FROM Transfers WHERE whatever)
```

You can create a view or stored procedure that saves `Max(seq)` if you need to reuse it in a transaction.

Comment: But that doesn't help record who inserted the row. Now does it tell you who authorized that person insert the row.

Comment: @Ian, sure it does, if you use the schema you told us; `Transfers.SentByUserName` tells you who inserted the row, `Transfers.SendApprovedBySupervisorUsername` tells you who approved it, and so on. If you update the rows this information is lost, so don't update; insert new records. Every transaction holds who inserted, approved, whatevered the row. Or insert into a separate table like Yahia suggests. If you allow updating old data you will never be able to do what you ask.

Comment: Ideally i wouldn't have those rows. Or at the very least when they ask for more *metadata* to be recorded (like they are today), i want to say no. Or at least: i don't want to store it with my data. The level of additional, almost always NULL, audit values is swamping the actual data.

Comment: @Ian, if you don't want those rows then don't add them. I have posted code that shows getting (possibly null) columns using the sequence ID as a foreign key.

Comment: A good example is "voiding" of a transfer. Most transfers will never be voided. But if they are they want to record the *date* it was voided, *who* voided it, the *computer* they voided it from, the *supervisor* who authorized it to be voided. Sometimes they also want a *reason* it was voided, a confirmation code from *surveillance* who watched it get voided. That's ten, nullable, almost always null, columns; and that's just related to "voiding" a transfer.

Comment: @Ian, create a `Voided` table, only add records to it when a transaction is voided, and perform an outer join against `Transfers` when you want to look for voided orders. If a column is sparse, then create separate tables for each sparse column and outer join them against the parent table. This is basic third-normal-form normalization. Yes, this may result in joining dozens of tables for a query. If this troubles you, consider creating views.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about SQL Server but when confronted with such in an Oracle scenario I tend to employ triggers (insert/update/delete) which take the complete row (before and after) into an "archive/audit" table and add whatever "metadata" they want logged along with it... this way my app-centric data model won't get poluted regarding applications/SPs etc. and no app/user has access to that sensitive logging/auditing information...

Comment: I like this answer. Why plug up your actual table with auditing information? You can keep much richer history and make much more flexible changes when you have a separate auditing table.

Comment: We already do audit the row using triggers into an audit table. Problem with that is that it doesn't record information that isn't recorded in the table.

Comment: you can either extend the trigger to record more information than available in that table (SELECTs/JOINs from other tables are usually no problem in a trigger)... or you could create an operations metadata table which gets filles with every operation done and/or you could do all changing activities (INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE) solely through Stored Procedures and revoke the app the respective rights...